# PHP Script works, perfect via. a Browser, but only sometimes via. Java

Tags: java, php, apache, http-status-code-401

I use this little PHP Script to create and deliver a captcha to a javaapplication:

```
<?php

$secretkey = "***";
header ( 'Content-type: text/xml' );

function generatePassword($length = 5) {
$chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
$count = mb_strlen($chars);

for ($i = 0, $result = ''; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $index = rand(0, $count - 1);
    $result .= mb_substr($chars, $index, 1);
}
return $result;
}

$user = $_POST['user'];
$key = $_POST['key'];
$captcha = generatePassword();

if ($key == $secretkey) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***", '***', '***');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        echo "<error>$error</error>";
    }
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO xf_captcha (username, captcha) 
        VALUES (:user, :captcha) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY 
        UPDATE captcha = :captcha",
        array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $sth->execute(array(':user' => $user, ':captcha' => $captcha));
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<captcha>$captcha</captcha>";
}
else {
    echo "<error>wrong key</error>";
}
?>
```

The Problem is, that sometimes the JavaApplication gets 401 Errors. The thing I don´t understand about this is, that it doesn´t seem to be related to the requests sent per minute.

If this is excecuted on a apache server without a ddos protection and big firewall, what could be the origin of denying the request ? Is this maybe Apache related ?

---

**Edit:**

The java part looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/Thi2Htwp

Comment: Can you share the relevant Java code?

Comment: @JosephRedfern no Idea why it is not working properly

Comment: Could this php script create a 401 error when the mysql connection didn´t succeed ?